# STMWIN connection to Azure IOT cloud

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded

I am trying to connect STMWIn starter kit to Microsoft azure.

I have successfully transferred the binary file which is taken from official ST site and transferred it to the board.
I was also able to configure the wifi credentials and the decide, scope ID.

After that on Tera Term it shows that
network interface starting

But in the cloud Azure there is no data incoming.

What could be the reason for same?

Comment: Azure is broken?